# relative url in asp.net website applications

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, relative-path

I have an image that I want to use it's src attribute in relative format

when my website URL was `http://localhost/` I used to use this code to access this image file:

```
<img alt="something" src="/Files/pic.png">
```

But now I have to add an application to my site and change my site URL to `http://localhost/mysite`.

Now none of my images load in this site because the path is still `http://localhost/Files/pic.png` not `http://localhost/mysite/Files/pic.png`

how can I change my root URL (`/`) to `http://localhost/mysite/`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tilde `~` in a server control to use a relative path.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImage" ImageUrl="~/Files/pic.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ~ symbol to represent root in ASP.Net

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Files/pic.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

@rrrr is right, that the way to do it,

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImage" ImageUrl="~/Files/pic.png" />
```

but I would use a standard html image with runat="server"

```
<img runat="server" src="~/YourPath/image.png">
```

Reason : less server side controls

Comment: <img runat="server"> is still a server-side control, it'll build in your page as a System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage rather than a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image like an <asp:Image runat="server"> would, so the difference it makes to resource consumption is negligible.