# Access image on IIS server from client via Url | ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, api, iis

My application is an Api ASP.Net, and I save the images in the `"wwwroot"` folder

**Content**

[image]

When I publish my application that structure is created as well and I want to access the images through a URL

**From Client Angular 2**

```
<img  src="{{ 'http://192.168.1.20/Api/api/uploads/Koala.jpg'}} " > 
(Not Found)
```

*I must mention, that my application is published locally, and users connected to the network must access the images*

**Question**

How to access the image found on the IIS server with the Url?
I am right?
Correct me if I'm wrong
Thank you all

Comment: You are using angular?

Comment: @Ivan-San yes ,

Comment: You don't need to use the {{ }} for the path, remove it and leave it just like in my answer

Answer (score 3):

First try to access the image url on the browser i.e.,

http://localhost/Api/api/uploads/Koala.jpg

If it displays the image then there is not problem with you IIS hosting.

Now try the same url from a different machine in the network i.e.,

http://192.168.1.20/Api/api/uploads/Koala.jpg (from a different machine)

If it does not work then make sure that you machine accepts http inbound traffic over the network.

Comment: In the first test it does not work, for that reason mention what type of project is

Comment: If you are not able to access it locally after publishing ( I am assuming rest of the app is working) then the problem is with hosting. is there any authentication on your app?

Comment: if there is authentication, but in the controllers, I have no idea if this also affects the static files

Answer (score 0):

Use tilde `~` for [relative URL in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9718858/8265882):

```
<img  src="{{ '~/uploads/Koala.jpg'}} " >
```

Comment: I want to access from the client, is this valid?

Comment: Yes is valid but it works if you are under the .net background, if you're handling the URL in the frontend maybe it does not going to work

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you shouldn't specify the full URL in `<img src="{{ }}">.`

If you want to specify full URL in Src attribute, you don't need angular. You should just remove `{{''}}` and modify the URL to

```
<img  src="http://192.168.1.20/Api/api/uploads/Koala.jpg" >
```

If you want to use angular2 in this case, you should just modify the URL like

```
 <img src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

Then declare the variable **imageUrl** in Component.